# IPython display always displays widgets before Text/Markdown

Tags: python, widget, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a project on the Jupyter Notebook using the IPython module, and I am trying to display widgets and Markdown-formatted text at the same time. However, I am unable to display text before displaying the widgets. The following code snippet, for example:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, Markdown

display(Markdown("## Enter your name"))
name = widgets.Text(description="Enter your name: ")
display(name)
```

displays [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tweT.png), even though I asked to display the markdown before displaying the widget. How can I force Jupyter Notebook to display in the order I want?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this bug has been fixed in the latest version 7 of ipywidgets. Try the same code after updating to 7.0. You can upgrade with following command (assuming you are running on anaconda).

```
conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets
```

If it still doesn't work for you try using [dominate](https://github.com/Knio/dominate) and the HTML widget. First install dominate from the command line, `pip install dominate` then you can run the following;

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from dominate import tags
from IPython.display import display

header = widgets.HTML(tags.h2("Enter your name").render())
name = widgets.Text(description="Enter your name: ")

display(header, name)
```

For an improved layout here is the same code from above with the `HBox` and `Label` widgets;

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from dominate import tags
from IPython.display import display

header = widgets.HTML(tags.h3("Enter your name").render())
name = widgets.Text()
namebox = widgets.HBox([widgets.Label("Enter your name: "), name])

display(header, namebox)
```

Comment: That helps me a lot! Thank you!